# Having frames next to each other in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I want to place a clock at one side of the screen and text at the other, I use frames. How can I do this. Here's a picture of what it looks like now:[image]

I want to make it so the clock is in line with the text on the same row but seperate labels. Take a look at my code and see if you could help me in someway, please!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
root.state("zoomed")  #to make it full screen

root.title("Vehicle Window Fitting - Management System")
root.configure(bg="grey80")

Title = Frame(root, width=675, height=50, bd=4, relief="ridge")
Title.pack(side=TOP, anchor='w')
titleLabel = Label(Title, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), text="Vehicle Window Fitting - Management System", bd=5, anchor='w')
titleLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

clockFrame = Frame(root, width=675, height=50, bd=4, relief="ridge")
clockFrame.pack(side=TOP, anchor='e')
clockLabel = Label(clockFrame, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd=5, anchor='e')
clockLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
curtime = ""

def tick():
    global curtime
    newtime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if newtime != curtime:
        curtime = newtime
        clockLabel.config(text=curtime)
    clockLabel.after(200, tick)
tick()

Bottom = Frame(root, width=1350, height=50, bd=4, relief="ridge")
Bottom.pack(side=TOP)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One issue is trying to mix the `pack` and `grid` layout managers as they don't play well together. Below is something that just uses `pack`. (Note you *can* use either one within a frame, just not both at the same time.)

To get the two items on the same "line", another `Frame` named `topFrame` has been added and the `titleLabel` and `clockFrame` widgets nested inside that. This grouping allows them both to be acted-upon as a single unit when moved or positioned — automatically affecting both of them but retaining their relative positions (`LEFT` and `RIGHT`) to one another.

I also removed the `curtime` global variable because it wasn't really necessary (as you can see by the modified `tick()` function).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
root.state("zoomed")  #to make it full screen

root.title("Vehicle Window Fitting - Management System")
root.configure(bg="grey80")

topFrame = Frame(root, width=1350, height=50)  # Added "container" Frame.
topFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=1, anchor=N)

titleLabel = Label(topFrame, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),
                   text="Vehicle Window Fitting - Management System",
                   bd=5, anchor=W)
titleLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

clockFrame = Frame(topFrame, width=100, height=50, bd=4, relief="ridge")
clockFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)
clockLabel = Label(clockFrame, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd=5, anchor=E)
clockLabel.pack()

Bottom = Frame(root, width=1350, height=50, bd=4, relief="ridge")
Bottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X, expand=1, anchor=S)

def tick(curtime=''):  #acts as a clock, changing the label when the time goes up
    newtime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if newtime != curtime:
        curtime = newtime
        clockLabel.config(text=curtime)
    clockLabel.after(200, tick, curtime)

tick()  #start clock
root.mainloop()
```

Here's what it looks like running:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I didn't see that. Placing a frame inside of a frame instead of inside the root, brilliant. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @Sam: Glad to hear it helped. Note I just stuck the `Bottom` `Frame` on the bottom of `root` (with the `side=BOTTOM` option). Wasn't sure if that's where you wanted it or directly under the new `topFrame` instead. Should be easy to change...

Answer (score 2):

I would create a frame for the header, and use something like `header.pack(side="top", fill="x")`. Then, I would put the two labels in that frame, packing one to the left and one to the right.

I would then add a second frame to fill the rest of the GUI, and all other widgets would go in that space.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grid(row=x, column=y)`. It makes adjacent object placing much easier.
Also, consider using just one frame for something.
You also don't need to specify width, really (unless if you use `pack/grid_propagate(0)`).

```
frame_1 = Frame(root, width=675, height=50)
frame_1.pack(side=TOP)

title_lbl = Label(frame_1, text="Lol whateva", height=50, bd=4, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), relief="ridge", anchor=wherever_you_need_this_to_be)
title_lbl.grid(row=n, column=n)

clock_lbl = Label(clockFrame, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd=5, anchor=wherever_you_need_this_to_be)
clock_lbl.grid(row=n, column=n)
```

You also didn't need more than one frame, just one frame for each label. It's a bad idea, really and it also consumes more time and typing.